# Can't join into a cluster on marklogic

Tags: cluster-computing, marklogic

I'm working with marklogic database and I tried to create a cluster.
I already have a development key. The OS is the same in all the nodes (win 7 x64).

When you tried to add a node into the cluster, you need to type the host name or the IP adress. For some reason when I type de host name, marklogic sometimes can't find the node , but that doesn't matter, because with the IP, the connection is successfull.

The main problem is when continues trought the process. At the end when marklogic try to transfer cluster configuration information to the new host, the process never ends and finally a message like "No data received" appear in the web browser.

I know that this message doesnt mean that the process fails, because when I change for example the host name, the same message appear.

So, when I check the summary in the first node, the second node appears, so that means the node "joins" into the cluster, but I'm not able to start the admin interface and always the second node appears disconnected even if I restart the service.

Aditionally, I'm able to make a ping from any computer to another.
I tried to create another network, because in my school some ports are not allowed, furthermore I tried to use different development key and the same key in my nodes too, 
and finally I already have all the services enabled, but the problem persist.

Any help or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of MarkLogic?

Comment: BTW, sounds like problems on the second node, so I'd ignore the first node for a while and make sure you can admin MArkLogic on the second node.  The first node's admin page shows the second node there but not joined, you say, which just means it knows you tried to add it, but doesn't mean they actually talked successfully.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm actually working with marklogic 7, the latest release. When you initialize the node by first time, marklogic ask you if you want to join into a cluster. You can actually skip this step and work in localhost, and I'm able to work in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure ports 7998 - 8003 are open on both computers for both inbound and outbound traffic and that you don't have a firewall (Windows firewall, or iptables) blocking these.

You can also start looking into the Logs/ErrorLog.txt file and see if something obvious shows up.

Stick to IP addresses for now as it seems your DNS isn't fully working.

Your error looks like a kind of networking connectivity problem between the hosts.

Also you might get more detailed, or atleast different, answers from the MarkLogic developer mailing list.

http://developer.marklogic.com/discuss

-David Lee

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the host names in MarkLogic configuration match the DNS names at which the hosts can see each other. If those are unreliable, then simply use IP addresses as host names. Go to the Admin interface on both ends, lookup the host name, change the DNS name into IP name, try again.

Also look at DALDEI's suggestion about ports and firewalls, that could be interfering as well.

HTH!